# Mysql Batch insert around 11 GB data from one table to another

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert, batch-insert

I want to copy all data from one table to another and also want to minimise downtime by reducing locking time during data copy process.

I am trying to do something like this

```
INSERT INTO temp_table SELECT * FROM old_table ORDER BY id;
```

But it's taking around 45 mins to copy. How could i batch process this to reduce lock time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188427/mysql-efficiently-copy-all-records-from-one-table-to-another

Comment: @kmoser I believe that comment 4 in the link you shared is a good approach !!  dump export-import is always faster.

Comment: [pt-archiver](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-archiver.html#name)

Comment: I am checking with LOCK TABLE option. Will update statistics